# What are the best detection medias for cholera?

Tags: homework, microbiology

I heard this fact that you can use some [hypertriade] for vibrio cholera diagnosis which has compontents

- sucrose (yellow)
- mannose (yellow)
- arabinose (do not ferment; stay dark pink)

I did not find this hypertriade agar on Google. 
It reminds me of Egg Yolk Agar, but I think cannot be it because of the arabinose.
Otherwise, it seems to be similar.

What are the best detection medias for cholera?

Comment: I don't see how you could have a single medium that would simultaneously test for fermentation/non-fermentation of three different sugars. From the colours that you mention this is clearly based on a tetrazolium salt, but if all three sugars were present then two of them would be fermented and you would get a conversion to a yellow product, regardless of the inability to ferment arabinose.

Comment: @AlanBoyd I added an explanation what the hypertriad may refer to: there can be three selective media in one petri dish. I am not sure why they are using the word hypertriade or hypertriad. They seem to be using only sucrose, mannose and arabinose. **Is there any collective name for such combination?**

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't be using TCBS?  Why the "hypertriade" in the first place?  If you're designing a specimen screen, you might use 4 instead. I also, I've never heard the phrase hypertriade, and DDG/Google failed to teach me. Do you have a reference for that term?

Comment: @AtlLED Make that an answer and I will accept it. I do not know why the assistant was using the word hypertriade. I have no idea of the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Thiosulfate-citrate-bile salts-sucrose agar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiosulfate-citrate-bile_salts-sucrose_agar) for the detection of all vibros, including cholera.  When cholera is presant, you should expect round, largish (not huge), yellow colonies.  This is the CDC [recommended](http://www.cdc.gov/cholera/diagnosis.html) diagnoses method.

Again this question might be better phrased "what are the best detection medias for cholera," or "what plate screens should be conducted when vibros are suspected?"